# Why does this query take so long?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a complex query I need to run on a MySQL-server.

On my home testing box, a mac, the query takes a reported 0.00 seconds and returns the reslut instantly.

On my server however, an ubuntu box, the same query takes around 3.30 minutes, using the same data.

The database uses InnoDB tables. The ubuntu box has a 64-bit kernel, and mysql is compiled for this.

Why does the ubuntu server take so much longer time to execute the query?

These are the configuration variables from the ubuntu-box:

```
mysql> show variables;
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                       |
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| auto_increment_increment        | 1                           | 
| auto_increment_offset           | 1                           | 
| automatic_sp_privileges         | ON                          | 
| back_log                        | 50                          | 
| basedir                         | /usr/                       | 
| binlog_cache_size               | 32768                       | 
| bulk_insert_buffer_size         | 8388608                     | 
| character_set_client            | latin1                      | 
| character_set_connection        | latin1                      | 
| character_set_database          | utf8                        | 
| character_set_filesystem        | binary                      | 
| character_set_results           | latin1                      | 
| character_set_server            | latin1                      | 
| character_set_system            | utf8                        | 
| character_sets_dir              | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/  | 
| collation_connection            | latin1_swedish_ci           | 
| collation_database              | utf8_danish_ci              | 
| collation_server                | latin1_swedish_ci           | 
| completion_type                 | 0                           | 
| concurrent_insert               | 1                           | 
| connect_timeout                 | 10                          | 
| datadir                         | /var/lib/mysql/             | 
| date_format                     | %Y-%m-%d                    | 
| datetime_format                 | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s           | 
| default_week_format             | 0                           | 
| delay_key_write                 | ON                          | 
| delayed_insert_limit            | 100                         | 
| delayed_insert_timeout          | 300                         | 
| delayed_queue_size              | 1000                        | 
| div_precision_increment         | 4                           | 
| keep_files_on_create            | OFF                         | 
| engine_condition_pushdown       | OFF                         | 
| expire_logs_days                | 10                          | 
| flush                           | OFF                         | 
| flush_time                      | 0                           | 
| ft_boolean_syntax               | + -><()~*:""&|              | 
| ft_max_word_len                 | 84                          | 
| ft_min_word_len                 | 4                           | 
| ft_query_expansion_limit        | 20                          | 
| ft_stopword_file                | (built-in)                  | 
| group_concat_max_len            | 1024                        | 
| have_archive                    | YES                         | 
| have_bdb                        | NO                          | 
| have_blackhole_engine           | YES                         | 
| have_compress                   | YES                         | 
| have_crypt                      | YES                         | 
| have_csv                        | YES                         | 
| have_dynamic_loading            | YES                         | 
| have_example_engine             | NO                          | 
| have_federated_engine           | DISABLED                    | 
| have_geometry                   | YES                         | 
| have_innodb                     | YES                         | 
| have_isam                       | NO                          | 
| have_merge_engine               | YES                         | 
| have_ndbcluster                 | DISABLED                    | 
| have_openssl                    | DISABLED                    | 
| have_ssl                        | DISABLED                    | 
| have_query_cache                | YES                         | 
| have_raid                       | NO                          | 
| have_rtree_keys                 | YES                         | 
| have_symlink                    | YES                         | 
| hostname                        | databaseserver              | 
| init_connect                    |                             | 
| init_file                       |                             | 
| init_slave                      |                             | 
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size | 8388608                     | 
| innodb_autoextend_increment     | 8                           | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_awe_mem_mb   | 0                           | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_size         | 1073741824                  | 
| innodb_checksums                | ON                          | 
| innodb_commit_concurrency       | 0                           | 
| innodb_concurrency_tickets      | 500                         | 
| innodb_data_file_path           | ibdata1:10M:autoextend      | 
| innodb_data_home_dir            |                             | 
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index      | ON                          | 
| innodb_doublewrite              | ON                          | 
| innodb_fast_shutdown            | 1                           | 
| innodb_file_io_threads          | 4                           | 
| innodb_file_per_table           | OFF                         | 
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  | 2                           | 
| innodb_flush_method             | O_DIRECT                    | 
| innodb_force_recovery           | 0                           | 
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout        | 50                          | 
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                         | 
| innodb_log_arch_dir             |                             | 
| innodb_log_archive              | OFF                         | 
| innodb_log_buffer_size          | 4194304                     | 
| innodb_log_file_size            | 5242880                     | 
| innodb_log_files_in_group       | 2                           | 
| innodb_log_group_home_dir       | ./                          | 
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      | 90                          | 
| innodb_max_purge_lag            | 0                           | 
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups      | 1                           | 
| innodb_open_files               | 300                         | 
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout      | OFF                         | 
| innodb_support_xa               | ON                          | 
| innodb_sync_spin_loops          | 20                          | 
| innodb_table_locks              | ON                          | 
| innodb_thread_concurrency       | 8                           | 
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay       | 10000                       | 
| interactive_timeout             | 28800                       | 
| join_buffer_size                | 131072                      | 
| key_buffer_size                 | 16777216                    | 
| key_cache_age_threshold         | 300                         | 
| key_cache_block_size            | 1024                        | 
| key_cache_division_limit        | 100                         | 
| language                        | /usr/share/mysql/english/   | 
| large_files_support             | ON                          | 
| large_page_size                 | 0                           | 
| large_pages                     | OFF                         | 
| lc_time_names                   | en_US                       | 
| license                         | GPL                         | 
| local_infile                    | ON                          | 
| locked_in_memory                | OFF                         | 
| log                             | OFF                         | 
| log_bin                         | OFF                         | 
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF                         | 
| log_error                       |                             | 
| log_queries_not_using_indexes   | OFF                         | 
| log_slave_updates               | OFF                         | 
| log_slow_queries                | ON                          | 
| log_warnings                    | 1                           | 
| long_query_time                 | 1                           | 
| low_priority_updates            | OFF                         | 
| lower_case_file_system          | OFF                         | 
| lower_case_table_names          | 0                           | 
| max_allowed_packet              | 16777216                    | 
| max_binlog_cache_size           | 18446744073709547520        | 
| max_binlog_size                 | 104857600                   | 
| max_connect_errors              | 10                          | 
| max_connections                 | 100                         | 
| max_delayed_threads             | 20                          | 
| max_error_count                 | 64                          | 
| max_heap_table_size             | 16777216                    | 
| max_insert_delayed_threads      | 20                          | 
| max_join_size                   | 18446744073709551615        | 
| max_length_for_sort_data        | 1024                        | 
| max_prepared_stmt_count         | 16382                       | 
| max_relay_log_size              | 0                           | 
| max_seeks_for_key               | 18446744073709551615        | 
| max_sort_length                 | 1024                        | 
| max_sp_recursion_depth          | 0                           | 
| max_tmp_tables                  | 32                          | 
| max_user_connections            | 0                           | 
| max_write_lock_count            | 18446744073709551615        | 
| multi_range_count               | 256                         | 
| myisam_data_pointer_size        | 6                           | 
| myisam_max_sort_file_size       | 9223372036853727232         | 
| myisam_recover_options          | BACKUP                      | 
| myisam_repair_threads           | 1                           | 
| myisam_sort_buffer_size         | 8388608                     | 
| myisam_stats_method             | nulls_unequal               | 
| ndb_autoincrement_prefetch_sz   | 1                           | 
| ndb_force_send                  | ON                          | 
| ndb_use_exact_count             | ON                          | 
| ndb_use_transactions            | ON                          | 
| ndb_cache_check_time            | 0                           | 
| ndb_connectstring               |                             | 
| net_buffer_length               | 16384                       | 
| net_read_timeout                | 30                          | 
| net_retry_count                 | 10                          | 
| net_write_timeout               | 60                          | 
| new                             | OFF                         | 
| old_passwords                   | OFF                         | 
| open_files_limit                | 1024                        | 
| optimizer_prune_level           | 1                           | 
| optimizer_search_depth          | 62                          | 
| pid_file                        | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid  | 
| plugin_dir                      |                             | 
| port                            | 3306                        | 
| preload_buffer_size             | 32768                       | 
| profiling                       | OFF                         | 
| profiling_history_size          | 15                          | 
| protocol_version                | 10                          | 
| query_alloc_block_size          | 8192                        | 
| query_cache_limit               | 1048576                     | 
| query_cache_min_res_unit        | 4096                        | 
| query_cache_size                | 16777216                    | 
| query_cache_type                | ON                          | 
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate    | OFF                         | 
| query_prealloc_size             | 8192                        | 
| range_alloc_block_size          | 4096                        | 
| read_buffer_size                | 131072                      | 
| read_only                       | OFF                         | 
| read_rnd_buffer_size            | 262144                      | 
| relay_log                       |                             | 
| relay_log_index                 |                             | 
| relay_log_info_file             | relay-log.info              | 
| relay_log_purge                 | ON                          | 
| relay_log_space_limit           | 0                           | 
| rpl_recovery_rank               | 0                           | 
| secure_auth                     | OFF                         | 
| secure_file_priv                |                             | 
| server_id                       | 0                           | 
| skip_external_locking           | ON                          | 
| skip_networking                 | OFF                         | 
| skip_show_database              | OFF                         | 
| slave_compressed_protocol       | OFF                         | 
| slave_load_tmpdir               | /tmp/                       | 
| slave_net_timeout               | 3600                        | 
| slave_skip_errors               | OFF                         | 
| slave_transaction_retries       | 10                          | 
| slow_launch_time                | 2                           | 
| socket                          | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock | 
| sort_buffer_size                | 2097144                     | 
| sql_big_selects                 | ON                          | 
| sql_mode                        |                             | 
| sql_notes                       | ON                          | 
| sql_warnings                    | OFF                         | 
| ssl_ca                          |                             | 
| ssl_capath                      |                             | 
| ssl_cert                        |                             | 
| ssl_cipher                      |                             | 
| ssl_key                         |                             | 
| storage_engine                  | MyISAM                      | 
| sync_binlog                     | 0                           | 
| sync_frm                        | ON                          | 
| system_time_zone                | CEST                        | 
| table_cache                     | 64                          | 
| table_lock_wait_timeout         | 50                          | 
| table_type                      | MyISAM                      | 
| thread_cache_size               | 8                           | 
| thread_stack                    | 131072                      | 
| time_format                     | %H:%i:%s                    | 
| time_zone                       | SYSTEM                      | 
| timed_mutexes                   | OFF                         | 
| tmp_table_size                  | 33554432                    | 
| tmpdir                          | /tmp                        | 
| transaction_alloc_block_size    | 8192                        | 
| transaction_prealloc_size       | 4096                        | 
| tx_isolation                    | REPEATABLE-READ             | 
| updatable_views_with_limit      | YES                         | 
| version                         | 5.0.75-0ubuntu10.5-log      | 
| version_comment                 | (Ubuntu)                    | 
| version_compile_machine         | x86_64                      | 
| version_compile_os              | debian-linux-gnu            | 
| wait_timeout                    | 28800                       | 
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT work.id work \
, count( DISTINCT( u.id ) ) number_of_editions \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( u.main_title ) ) main_title \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( main_author.full_name ) ) main_author \
, CONCAT_WS(' ', \
     GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( u.sub_title_1 ) ) \
    ,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( u.sub_title_2 ) )  \
    ,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( u.sub_title_3 ) )  \
    ,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( u.sub_title_4 ) )  \
    ,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( u.sub_title_5 ) )  \
    ,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( u.alternative_title ) )   \
    ,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( sst.title ) )  \
    ) boktitler \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( a.full_name ) ) authorname \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( lp.name )) literary_award \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( f.name )) publisher \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( st.title )) series \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( otn.time )) about_period \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( ostn.place )) about_place \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( opn.full_name )) about_person \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( eon.tag )) utag \
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT( pt.title )) parallell_title \
, work.owners number_of_owners \
FROM core_work work \
LEFT \
JOIN core_edition u \
    ON u.work_id = work.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_author main_author \
    ON main_author.edition_id = u.id AND main_author.nr = 1 \
LEFT \
JOIN core_conjoined_title sst \
    ON sst.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_parallell_title pt \
    ON pt.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_editiontag eo \
    ON eo.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_utag eon \
    ON eon.id = eo.tag_id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_edition_about_persons op \
    ON op.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_about_person opn \
    ON opn.id = op.about_person_id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_edition_about_place ost \
    ON ost.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_about_place ostn \
    ON ostn.id = ost.about_place_id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_edition_abouttime ot \
    ON ot.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_abouttime otn \
    ON otn.id = ot.abouttime_id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_seriesnr vs \
    ON vs.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT  \
JOIN core_series st \
    ON st.id = vs.series_id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_edition_publisher uf \
    ON uf.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_publisher f \
    ON f.id = uf.publisher_id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_author a \
    ON a.edition_id = u.id AND a.nr > 1 \
LEFT \
JOIN core_awarded_literary_award tlp \
    ON tlp.edition_id = u.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_literary_award lp \
    ON tlp.literary_award_id = lp.id \
LEFT \
JOIN core_source source \
    ON u.source_id = source.id \
WHERE u.hidden = 0 \
AND number_of_editions > 0 \
GROUP \
   BY work.id \
LIMIT 1;
```

The data in the two databases should be identical (I dumped to file from one and restored to the other). When I do EXPLAIN SELECT, there is a difference between the answers: (Identical rows edited out)

Fast testing machine:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys                         | key                                   | key_len | ref                               | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | work        | index  | PRIMARY,work_number_of_editions       | PRIMARY                               | 4       | NULL                              |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Slow machine:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys                         | key                                   | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | work        | range  | PRIMARY,work_number_of_editions       | work_number_of_editions               | 5       | NULL                              | 106796 | Using where; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

This puzzles me; why does the ubuntu server report 106796 rows when it has the same data as the other? And why does the slow machine use filesort?

Comment: Have you compared the plans on both systems?

Comment: To get a better comparison between both servers add the SQL_NO_CACHE option.

Comment: @Dennis Haarbrink: SQL_NO_CACHE does nothing here.  It is a control for the query cache.

Comment: @Morgan Tocker: I know, but when query results get cached you get a faulty comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) on both servers. That will show which indexes are being used and how. If there's any differences in the setup on both machines, it should affect the query plan (e.g. some table is missing an index on your server).

Are the data sets on both machines the same? If you only have a small subset of the data on your home machine, and the full "larger" dataset on the server, that would also affect things. You're using a *lot* of DISTINCT modifiers and GROUP_CONCATS and joining a large number of tables. This could require the use of a fair number of temporary tables and you may be exceeding the available memory, forcing MySQL to use disk buffering, which is very slow compared to in-memory operations.

Comment: Now I have dumped all tables from the ubuntu box and imported to the test machine. They should now be identical. EXPLAIN SELECT is not the same however: I'll edit my question to include the different responses.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running on the home box? From the looks of the ubuntu server's version, it's from an older version, as Ubuntu 10.04LTS ships with v5.1.41.

Comment: On my testing box I run MySQL 5.5.2-m2 from macports on a mac.

Comment: That's a fairly big difference. 5.5 is the development/bleeding edge version with lots of internal changes, which could explain the differences in query performance. I'd suggest downgrading to a version closer to what's on your ubuntu box and see if that makes your Mac as slow as the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `OPTIMIZE` and `ANALYZE` all the tables

Comment: Now I have done both, and got all OK's on all. Unfortunately it did not improve performance.